# Tomcat-maven-plugin 401 error

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-plugin, maven-3

i am learning tomcat basics and while i tried to deploy my web-application on tomcat i am getting the following error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli) on project struts2-demoapp: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://localhost:8080/manager/html/deploy?path=%2FmkyWebApp&war= -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

as per this it seems war file location is not being passed to the tomcat manager.i have the following entries in my `tomcat-user.xml`

```
tomcat-users>
<user name="admin" password="admin" roles="admin,manager" /><!--
  NOTE:  The sample user and role entries below are wrapped in a comment
  and thus are ignored when reading this file. Do not forget to remove
  <!.. ..> that surrounds them.
-->

<role rolename="manager"/>
  <role rolename="admin"/>
  <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="admin,manager"/>


</tomcat-users>
```

here are the details of the `pom.xml`

```
<build>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/web.xml</packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
                <warFile>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.war</warFile>
                <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/html</url>
                <server>myserver</server>
                <path>/mkyWebApp</path>

        </configuration>
</plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
```

in my setting.xml there are the entries

```
<server>
      <id>Tomcat6.x</id>

      <username>admin</username>
      <password>admin</password>
    </server>
```

i am not sure what exactly is going wrong here.any help in this regard will be helpful.

Comment: Try to put 'localhost' instead of 'Tomcat6.x' in the 'id' field in settings.xml.

Comment: @Tarlog: what is the concept of using localhost? since using this value solved the issue so i am wondering

Comment: I'll add an explicit answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to map the credentials from your settings.xml to the server configuration at your pom.xml.

In your case, this is done but setting the `<id>` element of your server, to match the server's host name from the pom.xml.

Since you are pointing `localhost`, the id must be also `localhost`.
When you change  the hostname, you must also update settings.xml.

Comment: Thanks Tarlog for the description :)

Answer (score 6):

Change

```
<server>
  <id>Tomcat6.x</id>
  <username>admin</username>
  <password>admin</password>
</server>
```

to

```
<server>
  <id>myserver</id>
  <username>admin</username>
  <password>admin</password>
</server>
```

If you are using tomcat 7 use

```
 <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/html</url>
```

If tomcat 6

```
<url>http://localhost:8080/manager</url>
```

start tomcat run tomcat7:deploy or tomcat6:deploy

Answer (score 3):

It's in the [plugin configuration docs](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/configuration.html): the `server/id` tag in Maven settings must match the `configuration/server` value in your POM file, i.e. put `<server>Tomcat6.x</server>` in POM file.

There are some other minor issues with your `tomcat-maven-plugin` entry in the POM file:

1. you are missing the `<version>1.1</version>` tag,
2. the `/html` suffix in the Tomcat manager URL is unnecessary (cf. the default value for `<url>` tag).

Answer (score 1):

When I was also running into this problem. My issue was using the older

```
 <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
```

instead of using

```
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
```

My setup is as follows

**~/.m2/settings.xml**

```
    <settings>
        <servers>
            <server>
              <id>localhost</id>
              <username>tomcat</username>
              <password>tomcat</password>
            </server>
        </servers>
    </settings>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
            <url>http://localhost:8080/manager</url>
            <server>localhost</server>
    <path>/myapppath</path>         
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml**

```
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="manager"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="admin-gui,manager-gui,manager-script,tomcat,manager"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Answer (score 0):

I Advise you to use this plugin :

```
 <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
  <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.2</version>
```

It's very helpful with Tomcat7. I  Have the same issue with mojo `<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>`
but now, using **Cargo** plugin, the deploy run smooth as silk.