# maven tomcat7 deploy

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, maven

**POM.xml:**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/html</url>
        <server>myserver</server>
        <path>/test</path>
        <warFile>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.war</warFile>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**Eclipse used:** Eclipse indigo 3.7 with **m2e plugin**

modified 
Tomcat7/conf/**tomcat-users.xml**

```
 <role rolename="admin"/>
  <role rolename="manager"/>
  <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="admin,manager"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

**Context.xml**
Tomcat7/conf/context.xml, change `<context>` to

```
<Context antiJARLocking="true" antiResourceLocking="true">
```

under **apache-maven\conf\settings.xml**

add following entry under server tag:

```
  <servers>
    <server>
    <id>myserver</id>
    <username>admin</username>
    <password>admin</password>
    </server>
```

**Start tomcat server**.

**target** run: **tomcat:deploy** and **tomcat:undeploy**

getting following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:redeploy (default-cli) on project test: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://localhost:8080/manager/html/deploy?path=%2Ftest&war=&update=true -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

project name: **test**

war file name: **test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war**

similar issue found but didnot get much use: [Tomcat-maven-plugin 401 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338248/tomcat-maven-plugin-401-error)

[tomcat-maven-plugin 403 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410479/tomcat-maven-plugin-403-error)

Comment: Do you get a page loaded when you access this URL: `http://localhost:8080/manager/html`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `manager-gui` to the roles:

```
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="admin,manager,manager-gui" />
```

And restart Tomcat.

Make sure that your XML configuration files are in use. A simple way to do this is writing an unclosed tag inside them and checking the error messages. If you don't get any error message you've written in an unused XML.

Comment: after doing Manager-gui role, getting follwoing error:Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:redeploy (default-cli) on project test: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: FAIL - Context /test is defined in server.xml and may not be undeployed
[ERROR] FAIL - Application already exists at path /test

Comment: Remove the `<Context path="/test" ...` tag from `server.xml` and delete the `test.war` and `test` directory from Tomcat's `webapp` directory then try `mvn tomcat:redeploy` again.

Comment: when I do this changes application working fine. But if I do -mvn clean all server related xml files which I had modified( ie context.xml,server.xml, tomcat-users.xml)files are earsed and replaced as original file. why this is happening?

Comment: I usually start Tomcat from command line with `bin/startup.bat`. I found this way more reliable than starting Tomcat from Eclipse.

Answer (score 6):

Though a late answer , someone might find this useful.
If you are using maven3 and tomcat7.The below method worked for me.I was not aware of the change in application manager endpoint in tomcat7.

```
Environment - Apache Maven 3.0.4,apache-tomcat-7.0.34,Windows 7
```

Tomcat7 has changed its deployment end point from `http://tomcatserver:8080/manager/html` to `http://tomcatserver:8080/manager/text`  .

So my pom.xml will be

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <configuration>
           <url>http://tomcatserver:8080/manager/text</url>
           <server>tomcat</server>
          <path>/myWebApp</path>
         </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

In tomcat-users.xml

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
  <role rolename="manager-status"/>
  <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
  <role rolename="admin-script"/>

  <user username="root" password="root" roles="manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status,admin-gui,admin-script"/>
```

In maven settings.xml

```
<server>
  <id>tomcat</id>
  <username>root</username>
  <password>root</password>
</server>
```

In context.xml , though this is optional and is not related to maven3 deployment to tomcat7 ,sometimes jar locking might happen,so to be on the safer side.

```
<Context  antiJARLocking="true" antiResourceLocking="true">
```

Now issue

```
mvn tomcat:deploy
```

Remember to start tomcat before maven deployment.

If deployment is success , your application will be available at

```
http://tomcatserver:8080/myWebApp
```

Answer (score 1):

in tomcat 7 you should set

```
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-script,manager-gui" />
```

to deploy using maven plugin

Comment: Thank you very very very much mate. I have been struggling to get this working for a couple of hours now. I've been getting a 403 error each time I tried to deploy and adding `manager-script` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

For tomcat 7 you're using the wrong goals. Try tomcat7:deploy and tomcat7:undeploy instead.

Answer (score 0):

Found Quick Solution on Mentioned Website...

http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-deploy-a-maven-web-application-to-tomcat.html

Working as expected in Eclipse and Sprint Test Suite

Note :- I have used clean **tomcat:deploy**, worked perfectly for me.